# Function being called twice in runOnUiThread Android Studio java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I have a JavascriptInterface that calls a function to draw in a layout. This function needs to be run on the UI Thread. I don't know why, but it is always called twice, making my app fail. Can someone help me?

```
@JavascriptInterface
        public void cambiarIdioma(String idIdioma)
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    setupTabLayout(Integer.parseInt(idIdioma),false);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: can you check if you app is going in onPause state and then again calling onResume?

Comment: I put a Log.i in both onResume and onPause and it seems it only print the onResume one once at the beggining of the execution. onPause one is not printed.

Comment: then double check if your app is crashing and you are unable watch any exception!

Comment: The app doesn't crash, but calling the function twice makes the function not work properly. Also, I don't see any error message in the logcat.